# Removing NAs changes bar width in ggplot with facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, na, geom-bar, facet-grid

I am plotting the answers in a bar chart, which looks good when I use the whole dataset, including the NAs:

```
anm$Q42<-factor(anm$Q42,levels=c('once_per_week','once_per_month',
                                 'once_per_6months','once_per_year'))
ggplot(data = anm, aes(x=Q42,fill=District)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=F)+
  scale_fill_discrete(drop=F)+
  labs(title="Animal health providers", 
       subtitle='n=3',x="", y="Count") +
  facet_grid(~Q2)+
  ylim(0,6)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1),
        plot.title = element_text(face='bold'),
        text=element_text(size=10))+
  stat_count(geom='text',aes(label = ..count..,group=1),vjust=-2,size=2)+
  stat_count(geom='text',aes(label = paste0("(",round(..count..*100/3,1),"%",")"),group=1),vjust=-0.5,size=2)
```

[image]

However, when I subset the dataset I am using in ggplot to remove the NA answers, the bar width increases and the plot looks like this:

```
ggplot(data = na.omit(anm), aes(x=Q42,fill=District)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(drop=F)+
  scale_fill_discrete(drop=F)+
  labs(title="Animal health providers", 
       subtitle='n=3',x="", y="Count") +
  facet_grid(~Q2)+
  ylim(0,6)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1),
        plot.title = element_text(face='bold'),
        text=element_text(size=10))+
  stat_count(geom='text',aes(label = ..count..,group=1),vjust=-2,size=2)+
  stat_count(geom='text',aes(label = paste0("(",round(..count..*100/3,1),"%",")"),group=1),vjust=-0.5,size=2)
```

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I stop it??
It also happens when I subset the data before plotting, when I use `facet_wrap` or when I add `space='free'` to the `facet_grid`.

Here the example dataset:

```
District<-c('Ngorongoro','Ngorongoro','Ngorongoro','Misungwi','Misungwi','Mwanga')
Q2<-rep('Retail outlet', 6) 
Q42<-c('once_per_month','once_per_year','once_per_month',NA,NA,NA)
anm<-as.data.frame(cbind(District,Q2,Q42))
```

Comment: Please provide minimal working data. Is there something special about it? Some values are NA? I think it's a problem with your pre-processing.

Comment: the example dataset is exactly how my dataset looks like. I do not do any pre-processing from the original csv apart from adding the additional factors that I want it to display in the x-axis.

Comment: I mean, we cannot follow your analysis when you do not provide some data.

Comment: The problem with your question, as I see, is that it has nothing to do with the code itself, your provided code with your provided data produces the graph you want (at least in Rstuduo cloud), so it seems more of an issue with not deleted data or something like that

Comment: But that's the thing, the code as I wrote it here produces the plot with bigger bar widths, and I do not know why... I don' know what other data I could provide, I am working with a data frame like the one I construct at the end of the question, there is not more to it. When I run the code with the dataset I give here I get the "wrong" bars as soon as I exclude the NA answers.

Comment: @Ignacio2424 so for you the bar chart looks fine when you run the code above with the example data? Because then it might be sth wrong with my R. I updated all packages and Rstudio and everything, but then it seems to be some kind of bug??? Anyway I found out how to remedy it. Still weird.

Comment: @KathrinLoosli I created a [github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5211) that looks similar to this problem